Server files greater than 1GB from Nginx to chrome browser
I am trying to have my Nginx 1.14.1 on an AlmaLinux 8 machine serve private file larger than 1 GB. I am using a Chrome browser.
If the file size is less than 1GB, everything works as expected. However, if the file size is greater, say 2GB, this is what happens:
Download initiates correctly, and as far as the developer tools view in Chrome, bytes downloaded shows 2GB. Then the browser says "Saving File" but the resulting filesize is 4bytes. There are no errors in the nginx logs, no timeouts or other errors in the browser or developer tools.
The nginx config for that segment is:
    location /protected_pdf/ {
        internal;
        alias   /u01/rp/reports/pdfreports/;
        sendfile off;
        sendfile_max_chunk 5m;
         proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
         proxy_request_buffering off;
         client_max_body_size 0;
         proxy_buffering off;
    }

I have tried with sendfile on and off : same result.
I can't tell if this is a browser issue, client issue, or a server side issue. Given that developer tools says all 2G of data was received, it appears that it may be a client side issue.
I tried firefox, but the results seem to be the same.
Any help would be much appreciated.
